# Viewstate Problems loading dynamic Controls (with ListBox)

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

this is my frist question, I apologize if I do something wrong.
Also I'm new to Asp.net. Here is my Problem:

I have an "Add Control Button" which adds a User Control with nothing more than a preconfigured ListBox. (The Idea is adding UserControls, as many, as the User needs.) So far so good. When I mark an element inside ListBox, Selection gets lost after 1st postback (for example after clicking add control button).Seems to be a Lifecycle Problem, dunno. My faulty Solution (adjusted from what I found on the net) is as follows: I use a List to restore every User Control based in its ID. Thank you. Here's the code:

```cs
protected List<string> ControlsList
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["controls"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["controls"] = new List<string>();
        }
        return (List<string>)ViewState["controls"];
    }
}

//Restore Controls based on IDs in ControlsList
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);        

foreach (string contrID in ControlsList)
    { 
            Control c;
            c = LoadControl("v1.ascx");
            c.ID = "v1-" + contrID;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(c);
      }

//Button Click adds Control
protected void addControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control c;
    c = LoadControl("v1.ascx");
    c.ID = "v1-" + NextID.ToString();
    ControlsList.Add(c.ID);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

Here the User Control:

```
public partial class v1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    v1_ListBox1.DataSourceID = "A1Vm1_SqlDataSource";
    v1_ListBox1.DataTextField = "Vm1";
    v1_ListBox1.DataValueField = "Vm1";
    v1_ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change how your ViewState is saved

```
protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    var a = this.ControlsList;
    var b = base.SaveViewState();
    if (a.Count == 0 && b == null)
        return null;

    return new System.Web.UI.Pair(a, b);
}

protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    if (savedState == null)
        return;

    var pair = (System.Web.UI.Pair)savedState;
    if (pair.First != null)
    {
        foreach (var id in (IList<string>)pair.First)
        {
            // add the control
        }
    }

    if (pair.Second != null)
        base.LoadViewState(pair.Second);
}
```

This approach will let you first initialize the child controls and then load the viewstate for them.

You might also want to add [ViewStateModeByIdAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.viewstatemodebyidattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to this control that is adding the controls dynamically so that the loading of viewstate will not fail once you start removing the controls.

Comment: You are the man. I've been struggling with this a couple of days. Your Solution got me insight about the problem as well as the elegant way of solving it. thanks